# How to Extract the Count Value into a Variable - Used for ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell

I need to trap the Count value of 2 into a Count variable - how can I perform this?  The idea in this example is to loop continuously until two hotfixes are installed - which means I can perform a service restart.

C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-HotFix |? installedon -gt 4/13/2022 | Group installedon –NoElement

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
    2 4/14/2022 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Count` is a property of the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo) instances that 
[`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) (a built-in alias of which is `group`) outputs, so you can simply access the `Count` property on each object emitted by your pipeline:

```
$count =
  Get-HotFix | ? installedon -gt 4/13/2022 | Group installedon –NoElement |
    ForEach-Object Count
```

Note that `$count` will end up with an *array* of counts if the `Group-Object` call resulted in *multiple* groups.